# How to convert a Datetime string to standard mysql

Tags: php, datetime

I made a function in php to convert date and time coming from a txt to the mysql standard.
But she is turning the month wrong.
I have tried all these conversions but to no avail.
I would like your help because I don't know what else to do.

```
    function convertstringdate('05/02/202116:43:49'){
        
    $date = new DateTime($datetime);
      return date_format($date, "Y-m-d H:i:s");
    
    
    }
or

$input = '05/02/202116:43:49'; 
$date = strtotime($input); 
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

Comment: Is 05 or 02 supposed to be the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the format of your datetime-string I suggest you use [`createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) like so:

```php
$string = '05/02/202116:43:49';

$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/YG:i:s', $string);

var_dump(date_format($dateTime, "Y-m-d H:i:s"));
// output: string(19) "2021-02-05 16:43:49"
```

Note that I am not sure if 05 or 02 is supposed to be the month in your example, so if this seems wrong to you you might just have to switch around `d/m` in the format string and make it `m/d`.

For explanation what character means what poriton of the datetime, see the linked above documentation reference.

Comment: Thanks 02 is the month and in other ways this is being considered as day